# Strange indentation when using pre

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, pre

In C# I fill a field with strings. Every string is ending with "\r\n". Then I fill a website with this data using Razor:

```
<td style="max-width:130px; overflow-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre;"
     align="left">
     @item.Data
</td>
```

Output on the website:

```
          - first line     (about 13 additional empty spaces)
- second line
- third line
- fourth line and so on
```

Desired output:

```
- first line
- second line
- third line
- fourth line and so on
```

Should I provide more code?

EDIT:

HTML:

```
<td style="max-width:130px; overflow-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre;"
    align="left">
    firstline&#xD;&#xA;secondline
</td>
```

Solution:
Actually my code maid extension in Visual Studio added white space after <td ...>(many whitespace here)

Comment: Can you provide the actual generated HTML?

Comment: I added the HTML. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white spaces are generated by the "formatted" html source code.
You need to "uglify" the html code as well.

Before:

```
<tr>
    <td style="max-width:130px; overflow-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre;" align="left">
        firstline&#xD;&#xA;secondline
    </td>
</td>
```

After:

```
<tr>
    <td style="max-width:130px; overflow-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre;" align="left">firstline&#xD;&#xA;secondline</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your text/code inside your `white-space:pre;`, should start at the beginning of the line (no tabs or spaces). I have given an example below.

```html
<td style="max-width:130px; overflow-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre;"
    align="left">
firstline&#xD;&#xA;secondline
</td>
```